# Who is the highest selling non US comic book superhero?

Tags: comics, super-hero

There must be foreign comic book superheroes, protagonist characters with superhuman or magical abilities. Which superhero is the highest selling, therefore the most popular, superhero published outside of the United States? I'd like to know the name of that superhero and brand of comic he or she is featured in.

Comment: This is a bit vague if you don't say what you mean by “superhero”; as a genre, it's mostly defined by US productions. For example, does [Asterix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterix) count?

Comment: "There must be foreign superheroes?" is that a joke? Seriously though, "Monkey D Luffy" is a super ...hero-ish person. His "comic" One Piece has sold over 250 million volumes. The latest issue has sold 3.2ish million copies.

Comment: @Gilles Edited question. Magic is a great way to be a superhero.

Comment: I Assume that "most popular" means "units sold", and that we're talking about today. If not, Asterix probably takes the cake.

Comment: one piece is not a super heroe  comic, they save a help  some people but also they steal and are pirates, in mangas the concept of super heroe like superman its no too common,

Comment: Is Robin Hood a hero? I'd say so. By that same token I'd say Luffy and his crew are also. He is also super-powered, so I'd say he fits the bill.

Comment: In addition. Japan has had "Superman" style heroes (albeit, they are usually robots), but much like here, that has fallen from popularity (See: AstroBoy).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "Hero": [Monkey D Luffy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_D_Luffy)
Ability: Rubber Man
Comic: One Piece
Country: Japan
Publisher: Shueisha
Magazine: Shonen Jump

Last Issue: Sold 3.16 million copies.
To Date: Sold 250 million volumes.

Comment: Just to explain "rubber man". Luffy basically has the same "power" as Mr Fantastic. Also, the only reason why I'm not answering Asterix or the various "Duck" comics wildly popular in Europe, is that they sell a lot less than One Piece "today". If this were 10 years ago... different story.

Comment: actually luffy power it is a little diferent to  Mr Fantastic, Mr Fantastic can change they body form at will for enlarged periods of time. luffy cannot, luffy  it is more like a Rubber band(for example he it is immune to electricity and support a huge amount of physical damage and is a idiot ), in additional  that the history have 10 years at air and the author say they just go at middle of them http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_band

Comment: I said "basically" for that reason. The core of his ability is that he's rubber-like but can obviously stretch far beyond what rubber can. I added that comment because "Mr Fantastic" is considered a "super hero", and Luffy has a very similar super-human aspect, and is partial to heroic things. Just trying to validate his super-hero qualification. Believe me, I know everything about Luffy. Also, the comic began in 97, so it's been going on 15 years.

Comment: For you US citizens, Mangas and Comics are the same thing? Because we (french) consider it two very different things.

Comment: @Kalissar What is the difference?

Comment: Well there are a lot of them... and even classical _Bande dessinée_ (Asterix/Tintin for instance) is something entirely different from the other two.

Comment: @Kalissar They're really not different **at all**: *manga*, *manhua*, &c. are literally just the Japanese, Chinese, &c. words for comic books. There are cultural associations and more or less common stylistic features and tropes, but they're no more distinct than *bande dessinée* are from comic strips. Comic strips don't stop being comics when they're collected into graphic novels in Belgium, the States, or Japan and at that point all of them are comic books.

Answer (score 7):

[Son Goku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_Goku_%28Dragon_Ball%29), the hero of *Dragon Ball* and its many follow-ups. There's no doubt to his super-heroic credentials:

> Goku is introduced as an eccentric, monkey-tailed boy who practices martial arts and possesses superhuman strength. At first, Goku is believed to be an Earthling, but he is later revealed to be a member of an extraterrestrial warrior race called the Saiyans... As Goku matures, he becomes one of Earth's strongest warriors and protects it from villains who wish to harm it.

The original manga has sold over 300 million books worldwide (only *One Piece* has sold more comics); on top of this there are numerous spin-offs and shorter sequels, four anime series, twenty films, and [enough video games that is is also one of the biggest video game franchises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragon_Ball_video_games) as well.

Comment: dragon ball it is older  and have influenced a too many manga stories, but to day the most sold manga is one piece

Comment: @osdamv: _One Piece_ has sold more manga, but I would be surprised if it comes anywhere near _Dragon Ball_ as a franchise; similarly for Son Goku vs. Luffy as a character.

Comment: one piece never be popular than dragon ball in occident  one piece touch too many topics that in america are tabu, naruto could be..

Comment: @osdamv Statistically speaking, One Piece *is* more popular than Dragon Ball at the moment. It's very hard to rank popularity outside of sales figures. It has also produced 30-odd video games and 11 movies so far. So, it should be *somewhere* near.

Comment: hmm, I was not  clear  , with the censorship in cartoons,  the one piece anime has been raped for themes like beer, smoke and guns don't talk about ivankov, I am sure you saw the crap adaptation to english... that it is why I told that one piece would not be so popular like dragon ball in america :(

Comment: @osdamv Ah, I see. That's probably true. Luckily for OP it is raking in heavy fan-bases outside of the US.

Comment: @osdamv Who was raped in *One Piece*?

Answer (score 1):

I concur that asterix is probably the right answer, but maybe not exactly the US-style superhero.

Wikipedia [doesn't seem to offer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superhero_fiction#Superhero_fiction_outside_the_United_States) interesting options.

If batman counts as a superhero, than possibly [Super Duck/Paperinik/Duck Avenger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck_in_comics#Paperinik_.28Duck_Avenger.29) (donald duck's hero alter ego) could be the most known outside of north america, having been in print stories worldwide since the '70s, but originally created in italy.

Comment: Yay for the french hero ! But One Piece is the right answer :p